# Installing luarocks to use both lua5.1 and luajit on Ubuntu

Tags: lua, luajit, luarocks

I want to be able to run something like `luarocks-jit install X` and have the newly installed rock use luajit as it's interpreter. Ultimately, I'm trying to run my [busted tests through luajit](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted/pull/234).

Here's what I've tried:

Current versions of luarocks have a ["--lua-version"](http://luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Unix) flag in the configure script, but it only accepts "5.1" or "5.2", so no dice there. I've thought about editing that script to accept "jit" as well, but I haven't done it yet.

I've tried to follow this [wiki page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaRocksConfig), but it was written for a different OS and I'm suspicious it's out of date for a couple of reasons:

- I can't find any documentation for a lot of the variables it references (LUA_BINDIR, etc)
- The scripts at /usr/local/bin/luarocks5.1 on my machine look totally different than those 
  on the page.
- The config-X.lua files shown on the page also look rather different than what I have 
  installed.

Actually though, I'm having to do this on an unfortunately old version of Ubuntu (7.10) so perhaps it's more likely that it is my system that's out of date. Either way, I couldn't get luarocks-jit working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Nevermind, after messing with the luarocks configure script I realized that luajit is lua5.1 in a lot of ways. ./configure --lua-suffix=jit --with-lua=/usr seems to work on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021 : **lua-suffix is no longer necessary**

---

Once you have your luajit (2.0.5 as of today) installed and luarocks (3.7.0) extracted, use the following command :

```sh
./configure --lua-version="5.1"
```

which outputs

```sh
Configuring LuaRocks version 3.7.0...

Lua interpreter found: /usr/bin/luajit
Checking if /usr/bin/luajit is Lua version 5.1... yes
lua.h found: /usr/include/luajit-2.0/lua.h
unzip found in PATH: /usr/bin

Done configuring.

LuaRocks will be installed at......: /usr/local
LuaRocks will install rocks at.....: /usr/local
LuaRocks configuration directory...: /usr/local/etc/luarocks
Using Lua from.....................: /usr

* Type make and make install:
  to install to /usr/local as usual.
* Type make bootstrap:
  to install LuaRocks into /usr/local as a rock.
```

Comment: It's old I know, but how do I know which luarocks version belongs to lua-5.1.5 ?